# How to declare enum in validation file request for usertype

Tags: php, laravel, validation, eloquent, enums

hello i got a problem to declare a enum validation role in my table user, this is my code for store new user

```
    public function rules(){
        return [
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|unique:users|max:255',
            'role' => 'required|enum_value:' . UserType::class,
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'confirmed', Password::min(8)
                ->mixedCase()
                ->letters()
                ->numbers()
                ->symbols()
                ->uncompromised()],
        ];
    }
    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'name.required'    => 'Name for user is required',
            'role.required'    => 'Role user is required',
            'email.required'    => 'Email user is required',
            'email.unique'      => 'The email has already been taken. Try another email.',
            'password.required'    => 'Password user is required',
        ];
    }

    protected function failedValidation(Validator $validator)
    {
        return Alert::error(' Error Tambah Data ', ' Silahkan Periksa Kembali');
    }
```

and this is the blade for input the role

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="role">Role</label>
    @if(isset(Auth::user()->role))
    @if(Auth::user()->role === 1)
    <input type="text" class="form-control @error('name') is-invalid @enderror" id="role" placeholder="Writer" name="role" value="2" required autocomplete="name" autofocus readonly>
    @else
    <select class="form-select @error('role') is-invalid @enderror" name="role" id="roleCreate">
      <option selected>Select Role</option>
      @foreach ($arrUserType as $status=>$value)
      <option value="{{ $value }}">{{ $status }}</option>
      @endforeach
    </select>
    @endif
    @endif
    @error('role')
    <div class="invalid-feedback">{{ $message }}</div>
    @enderror
  </div>
```

and this is the controller

```
    public function store(UserPostRequest $request)
    {
        $validated = $request->validated();
        // dd($validated);
        $validated['password'] = Hash::make($validated['password']);
        $userId = $this->userService->storeUser($validated);
        Alert::success(' Berhasil Tambah Data ', ' Silahkan Periksa Kembali');
        return redirect()->route('users.index');
    }
```

I always get the error message "**The value you have entered is invalid.**"
in my opinion, I have a mistake in a declare validation request because the validation give an error message, I make this role with enum BenSampo/laravel-enum

so how to fixed it this error?, thank you !

Comment: Have you created enum_value validation rule? If so please share that  as well.

Comment: Does the "The value you have entered is invalid." message correspond to the `role` field?